# Local Reporting Services column not displaying value

Tags: reporting-services

I added a column to my DataSet and refreshed it in the report designer.  All shows up as expected.  Added it to my report, ran the app, but no values are displayed for the column; it's just blank.  If I try to perform ANY operation on the column, it generates the ever-helpful #Error error.  I paused execution after refreshing the dataset, and the values are showing up in the dataset as expected.  The values are integers, and I added them from two separate rows in debug without an error.  Any ideas where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I added the column to my dataset, I typed the name in all lowercase in the SQL statement; IE, `columnname`.  I then renamed it in the designer to `ColumnName`.  There were properties in the DataSet like Caption, Name and Source that retained the all-lower-case version of the name (can't remember which ones), even though the designer showed the capitalized name.  I edited the dataset's SQL and changed the SQL statement to select `ColumnName`, and all was well.  Weird problem.  Posting this here in case someone else runs into this.